# How do i compare string and integer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova

i have basicly no knowledge of objective c, but how do i make a if statement to see if SourceTypeString is equal to 1 or 2?

```cs
     NSString* sourceTypeString = [arguments objectAtIndex:2];
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; // default
            NSLog(@"my ns string = %@",sourceTypeString);
  //NEWBIE PART
        if ((sourceTypeString == 1))
            {
            NSLog(@"equals 1");
                sourceType = (UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)[sourceTypeString intValue];
            } else {
            NSLog(@"equals 2");
            sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }
   //NEWBIE PART
```

My code crashes and gives me

```
my ns string = 1
(lldb) 
sourceTypeString    __NSCFNumber *  0x0013bf80 (int)1
```

Comment: "i have basicly no knowledge of objective c" - In this case your question would probably be a better fit for an Objective-C tutorial or our ["teach me everything" sister site.](http://google.com)

Comment: Im not asking to learn. This is just a one time fix in Cordovas source. I will not go in and work in the objective c code again :). So thats why i didnt go (the learning) way.

Comment: again, that very sister site of ours has the answer. And this is not a very good attitude, by the way (says the community deducing from the score of this question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if ([sourceTypeString intValue] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `intValue` on an `NSString` to get its value as an `int`, if it is possible to do so with the given string.  Then you can compare those.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly compare ints to strings. However, you can use NSString's `isEqualToString` to check if the first strings value is equal to the string value of the number.

```
if ([sourceTypeString isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I keep getting error while running the app.

[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17a7a0

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17a7a0'

Comment: Well actually looking again you don't even have an NSString to begin with, it is an NSNumber

Comment: @borrrden Good call, need more coffee!